# Retrieving Facebook profile picture with graph / app access token?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm looking to use facebook profile pictures based on passing an ID and before the user authenticates.  The key thing here is I don't want to be rate limited so I need an access token and since user hasn't created one it must be app based.

I've done it this way which works (app access token generated with php-sdk) but would like to know if there's a better or more accepted way of retrieving it?

```
$url = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebook_id.'/picture?redirect=false&access_token='.$access_token.''))->data->url;
echo '<img src="'.$url.'" />';
```

The above code seems slower than retrieving without the access token.

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is much more easy way! 
You can directly use the user id:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/picture?return_ssl_resources=1" alt="" />
```

Fx. if you want to get Mark Zuckengerg picture you can use:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/112845672063384/picture?return_ssl_resources=1" alt="" />
```